# Swap entire arrays in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

When I try to make a function to swap 2 arrays, the original arrays are left unaltered.

```
function swap(x, y) {
    var temp = x; x = y; y = temp;
}

u=[1, 0];
v=[0, 1];
swap(u, v);
console.log(u);
console.log(v);
```

This results in u as [1, 0] and v as [0, 1]. The values haven't been changed after the function call to swap.

On the other hand, if I do this without a function call:

```
u=[1, 0];
v=[0, 1];
var temp = u;
u = v;
v = temp;
console.log(u);
console.log(v);
```

Then they're swapped correctly, with u as [0, 1] and v as [1, 0].

I thought Javascript arrays are passed by reference, not by value. Am I misunderstanding something here?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: u and v should be swapped. So u should be [0, 1] and v should be [1, 0]. I'll make it more clear in the question as well.

Comment: The fact that array's aren't **copied** doesn't mean they are passed "by reference". This is more similar to pass-by-pointer.

Comment: "I thought Javascript arrays are passed by reference, not by value. Am I misunderstanding something here?" Yes, JavaScript only has **pass-by-value**. The type of values is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are passed by reference, but they are also assigned by reference. When you write `x = y` you aren't modifying either of the arrays, you're just making your local variable `x` refer to the same array as `y`.

If you want to swap the array contents, you have to modify the arrays themselves:

```
function swap(x,y) {
    var temp = x.slice(0);
    x.length = 0;
    [].push.apply( x, y );
    y.length = 0;
    [].push.apply( y, temp ); 
}
```

Comment: Just to be clear, this isn't really a swap.  This is rewriting both arrays from scratch and isn't particularly efficient.  Perhaps that's what the OP wanted, but I sure wouldn't call this a swap in the usual sense of the word.

Comment: @jfriend00 Agreed. This answer is `Θ(n)` while your solution using a container object is `Θ(1)`. It also uses additional memory, since it copies `x`. They will be approximately the same speed for small arrays, but yours will definitely outperform this for large arrays. I would say that this version is a little easier to read and use though.

Comment: They are *not* passed by reference. The semantics are exactly the same as in Java. And Java is universally described on Stack Overflow as having no pass by reference.

Answer (score 8):

Javascript does not have the ability to pass a reference to the `u` and `v` variables themselves.  So, no assignment to `x` or `y` in your `swap()` function will change what is assigned to `u` or `v`.  Javascript passes a reference to the object that `u` and `v` hold.  Thus, you can't change the `u` and `v` variables from within `swap()`.  You can change the contents of the object that they point to and thus properties of the object that `u` and `v` point to can be modified.

Since I have a C/C++ background, I think of what Javascript does when passing objects as "pass by pointer".  When you call `swap(u, v)`, what is passed to the `swap()` function is a pointer to the array that `u` also points to.  So, now you have two variables `u` and `x` both "pointing" at the same array.  Thus, if you modify that actual array, then since `u` points at that same array, both will see the modification.  But, nothing you do inside the `swap()` function can change what object `u` or `v` actually point to.

---

In Javascript, the only way to change what object the original variables point to is to make them properties of an object and pass the object like this:

```
function swap(obj, x, y) {
    var temp = obj[x]; obj[x] = obj[y]; obj[y] = temp;
}

var container = {};
container.u = [1, 0];
container.v = [0, 1];
swap(container, "u", "v");
console.log(container.u);
console.log(container.v);
```

---

If you don't mind rewriting both arrays from scratch, you can copy all the contents of one array to a temporary, then copy one array over to the other and then copy the temporary array contents back to the first original.  This is not very efficient and there is probably a better way to solve your original problem, but it can be done.

```
 function swap(x, y) {
      // remove all elements from x into a temporary array
      var temp = x.splice(0, x.length);
      // then copy y into x
      x.push.apply(x, y);
      // clear y, then copy temp into it
      y.length = 0;
      y.push.apply(y, temp);
 }
```

Comment: I've used `std::swap()` in C++. Is there a way I can achieve the same thing in Javascript?

Comment: This is true pass by reference. In a language like `C` you can only pass by value, but you can pass references by value, and therefor you can also pass references to refereneces by value, which allows the behaviour the OP was expecting

Comment: @user3448821 - in Javascript, the only way to simulate a true reference that allows you to change what the original variable contains would be to make `u` and `v` by properties of an object and pass the containing object.  Then, you could swap the contents of those two properties.

Comment: @user3448821 - I added an example to my answer of swapping using an object.

Comment: @Paulpro - I tried to clean up the terminology I used in my answer to address your comment.

Comment: @user3448821 - I added a `swap()` option that copies all elements from one array to the other and vice versa.

Comment: @jfriend00 `Array.prototype.concat` doesn't modify the array, it returns a new one, with its argument arrays concatenated together. Your function empties both arrays. That is the reason I used `[].push.apply( x, y );`. You have my upvote for the swap using any container object anyway.

Comment: @Paulpro - my mistake.  I will correct.  Javascript drives me nuts in that it is not very clear about which array methods modify the array and which ones do not and the names tend to mislead you.  Not the first time I've goofed this.

Comment: @Paulpro: Like Java, JavaScript has ONLY pass-by-value.

Answer (score 1):

Getting the terminology on these "reference/value" questions is tricky, but I will do my best.

What you have for your Object / Array variables are really just references. Unlike C++, saying "x = y" does not actually copy the object's variables over to a new memory location. Internally, it's just copying a pointer location over. The language does not have constructions to "automatically recreate" something like an object or array in a new instance; if for some reason, you want to maintain two copies of an array, you will need to explicitly create it then copy over values (ie, `= [];` or `= new Array();` or a copying function like `= oldArray.map(...)`)

A little code example that might conceptually help. These same rules apply between objects and arrays.

```
a = {}; // In case you haven't seen it, this is like shorthand of "new Object();"
b = {};
c = b;
console.log(a === b); // false
console.log(b === c); // true
b.property = "hello";
console.log(c.property) // hello
```

Comment: "Unlike C++, saying "x = y" does not actually copy the object's variables over to a new memory location." It *is* like C++ -- in C++ it would be `Foo *y = ...; Foo *x = y;` The structure is the same.

Comment: @newacct Granted I think we're saying the same thing with different vocabulary but I'm not sure I agree about the similarity. In your two-line example, you are declaring a variable that contains a pointer. Then, you are creating another variable, and, from my point of view, *copying that pointer to a new memory location*. The compiler DOES have to allocate for those new 32/64 bits. So it would be like C++ if you were always only working with pointers for every single object (which I understand is a dangerous practice to just apply everywhere needlessly)

Comment: But that is exactly what the JavaScript code says. Types are just not written out in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Just like Java, JavaScript is **pass-by-value only**. Assigning to local variables in a function never has any effect on anything outside the function.

Answer (score 0):

### Feb 2022 Solution to Swap 2 Entire Array Contents.

You can use **destructuring** to swap the 2 arrays:

```
let a = [  1,  2,  3, 4 ];
let b = ['a','b','c','d'];

[a,b] = [b,a];   // swap

console.log(a);  // ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
console.log(b);  // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

```js
    let a = [  1,  2,  3, 4 ];
    let b = ['a','b','c','d'];
    
    [a,b] = [b,a];   // swap
    
    console.log(a);  // ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
    console.log(b);  // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

To swap 2 arrays you may use

**Version 1**

```
let arrA = [1,2,3,4];
let arrB = ['Eve', 'Bar', 'Foo'];

let tempArr = [arrA, arrB];  // constructing new array
arrA = tempArr [1];
arrB = tempArr [0];
```

**Version 1 (shorthanded)**

```
let arrA = [1,2,3,4];
let arrB = ['Eve', 'Bar', 'Foo'];
    
// RHS : construction a new array 
// LHS : destruction of array
[arrB, arrA ] = [arrA, arrB];
```

**Version 2 (spread operator)**

```
let arrA = [1,2,3,4];
let arrB = ['Eve', 'Bar', 'Foo'];

let arrC = [...arrB]
arrB = [...arrA]
arrA = [...arrC]
```